# How to generate a list of strings that ends with a sequence in R

Tags: r, function, loops, append

So I am trying to generate a list of strings with a prefix and ends with a number sequence like this:

`c("b01001_001", "b01001_002",...,"b01001_030")`  in R

And here is my code:

```
generate_var = function(prefix, length){
  varlist = c()
  i = 1
  while (i <= y){
    if (i < 10){
      var = paste(x, "_00", as.character(i), sep = " ")
    }
    if (i >= 10){
      var = paste(x, "_0", as.character(i), sep = " ")
    }
    varlist[[i]] = var
    i = i + 1
  }
}

varlist = generate_var("b01001", 30)
```

The function turns out generating an empty list. Can somebody help me look at my code and tell me what went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is `y`? You never create it. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R has vectorized functions, use `paste` with `sprintf`.

```
generate_var = function(prefix, length) {
   paste(prefix, sprintf('%03d', seq_len(length)), sep = '_')
   #Much better suggestion by @thelatemail
   #sprintf('%s_%03d', prefix, seq_len(length))
}

generate_var("b01001", 6)
#[1] "b01001_001" "b01001_002" "b01001_003" "b01001_004" "b01001_005" "b01001_006"
```

---

As far as your code is concerned there are few errors.

1) You use `x`, `y` in function but they are no where to be found, perhaps you meant `prefix` and `length`.

2) No need for `sep = " "` argument if you use `paste0` instead of `paste`.

3) Use single square brackets (`[]`) and not double brackets (`[[]]`) to access `varlist` since using double brackets turn `varlist` to a list.

4) In the end `return(varlist)`.

```
generate_var = function(prefix, length){
  varlist = c()
  i = 1
  while (i <= length){
    if (i < 10){
      var = paste0(prefix, "_00", as.character(i))
    }
     if (i >= 10){
       var = paste0(prefix, "_0", as.character(i))
    }
      varlist[i] = var
      i = i + 1
   }
   return(varlist)
}

generate_var("b01001", 5)
#[1] "b01001_001" "b01001_002" "b01001_003" "b01001_004" "b01001_005"
```

Comment: Why not make use of `sprintf` for the whole thing then - `sprintf('%s_%03d', prefix, seq_len(length))`?

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak! My first time writing a function in R. I still need to practice it more. I looked up paste and paste0 and indeed paste0 is a better option here.

Answer (score 4):

additional option

```
library(stringr)
str_c("b01001_", str_pad(1:30, width = 3, pad = 0))
```